# Implementing Session in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i'm new to spring mvc Can anybody help me out of how to implement session in spring MVC ? and in specific can i know what is the actual use of @SessionAttribute annotation ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically Spring’s @SessionAttributes is used on a controller to designate which model attributes should be stored in the session.

The for example defining like this in your controller

```
  @Controller
  @SessionAttributes("myRequestObject")
  public class MyController {
          ...
  }
```

And then the model Attribute will be added into HttpSession before render the view.
Then in your view you can access through the session attributes.

```
    <h3>Session Scope</h3>
    <%
        out.println(request.getSession().getAttribute(s));
    %>
```

Comment: Dont forget to marked as valid finish answer if you think that resolve  your issue